# Translate between Tcl and Python List

Tags: python, tcl

I want to know if the following parser covers every possible cases, and if the code can be cleaner/better organized.

Python 3 code:

```
def add_element(cache, element):
    if element != '':
        cache[-1].append(element)
    return ''


def to_py(raw_tcl_list):
    out = []
    cache = [out]
    element = ''
    escape = False
    for char in raw_tcl_list:
        if escape:
            if char not in ["\\", "{", "}", "[", "]", "$"]:
                raise ValueError("Incorrect escape character %s" % char)
            element += char
            escape = False
        elif char == "\\":
            escape = True
        elif char in [" ", "\t", "\r", "\n"]:
            element = add_element(cache, element)

        elif char == "{":
            a = []
            cache[-1].append(a)
            cache.append(a)

        elif char == "}":
            element = add_element(cache, element)
            if len(cache) < 2:
                raise ValueError("Close bracket without opening bracket.")

            cache.pop()
        else:
            element += char
    if len(cache) != 1:
        raise ValueError("Mismatched brackets.")
    return out[0]


def to_tcl(py_list):
    if type(py_list) == list:
        out_str = "{ "
        for item in py_list:
            out_str += to_tcl(item)
        out_str += "} "
        return out_str
    else:
        out_str = str(py_list) + " "
        for c in ["\\", "{", "}", "[", "]", "$"]:
            out_str = out_str.replace(c, "\\" + c)
        return out_str


import pprint

x = "{ 12 apple {100} {} {{12 34}} \n {56\n { \\{78 {11 12 11} 10}}}"
y = to_py(x)
z = to_tcl(y)
print("# Original #")
pprint.pprint(x)
print("\n# Translated to Python List #")
pprint.pprint(y)
print("\n# Translat back to Tcl List #")
print(z)
```

Output:

```
# Original #
'{ 12 apple {100} {} {{12 34}} \n {56\n { \\{78 {11 12 11} 10}}}'

# Translated to Python List #
['12',
 'apple',
 ['100'],
 [],
 [['12', '34']],
 ['56', ['{78', ['11', '12', '11'], '10']]]

# Translat back to Tcl List #
{ 12 apple { 100 } { } { { 12 34 } } { 56 { \{78 { 11 12 11 } 10 } } }
```

list of Tcl special characters: http://wiki.tcl.tk/989#pagetoceaa9fda9